# Desgin DFA that will accept strings having a's and b's divisible by 3?

Tags: automata

DFA - DETERMINISTIC FINITE AUTOMATA

for eg-abaabbbbb

number of a's - 3
number of b's -  6
which are divisible by 3

Comment: Do you know the principles of finite automata design?

Comment: sry my question was wrong it is about DFA

Answer (score 0):

If any string contain `a,b`  & it is divisible by 3 than it has 3 states i.e. q0,q1,q2. 
One is having remainder `0`
Second is having remainder `1`
Third is having remainder`2`